# limsups and liminfs

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits

Suppose we have a sequence $(x_n)$ in $\mathbb{R}$ such that $x_n \leq X $ for all $n$, then we have $$ \limsup x_n \leq X $$
 and if $X \leq x_n$ for all $n \implies X \leq \liminf x_n $.

My try. Since $x_n \leq X$, then $X$ is an upper bound for the set $\{ x_n \}$. In particular $ \sup \{ x_n \} \leq X $ if we then pass to the limits we have $ \limsup x_n \leq X $ as required. Similarly for liminf .

Is this correct? thanks for your comments.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your try looks correct to me.

I apologize for using the "t" word, but this seems like a trivial consequence of the definitions of $\lim\sup$ and $\lim\inf$. Under your assumptions,

$$\lim\sup_{n\to\infty} x_n \equiv \lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\sup\{x_m \mid m \geq n\}\right) \leq X  $$

because $x_m \leq X$ for all $m$.  Maybe I'm missing something.  The only thing that might not be obvious is the existence of $\lim\sup_{n\to\infty} x_n$.  Clearly, $\lim\sup_{n\to\infty} x_n$ is the limit of a nonincreasing sequence so it exists (it is a real number or $-\infty$).

You use a similar argument for the $\lim\inf$.